# Displaying Checkboxes in Show View instead of True or False Values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating an application for a security company I work for.. I have a few forms that are boolean value heavy and have a large number of checkboxes a user would go through to select various incident types / descriptions ect..

currently the checkbox i apply in my _form page is as follows:

```
<td><center><div class="control-group"><div class="controls"><%= f.check_box :on_site_owner %></div></div></center></td>
```

The display on my Show Page is as follows:

```
<td><center><div class="control-group"><div class="controls"><%= @resident_owner.on_site_owner %></div></div></center></td>
```

What i am hoping to accomplish is one of two things. and either will work great i just have no idea how to achieve it... and cant find much direction on it.

1) Populate a list on the show page with only the selected or "true" boxes.

2) only show true values instead of true and false values on the show page..

i would really prefer option one for ease of reading and so the client that will view it doesn't go into a true / false overload.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Your questions isn't clear. Do you want to show only the attributes that are true?If so how do you want to display? Also in your code for show page, do you not have any label at all or you just don't bother writing it? If there is no label, user cannot not know what the word 'true' represent.

Comment: There is a label present I just thought it would be redundant to post the label here. At the end of the day I would love all the checkboxes to appear either checked for true or not checked for false in the show page. Hope this clarifies I'm a bit of a posting noob. My apologies

Comment: So what you want is to show boolean values as checkboxes ,either checked or unchecked depending on its value, inside show page? Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using checkboxes in show page, you can use `check_box_tag` helper method. Documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag). Eg:

```
<td>
 <center>
   <div class="control-group">
     <div class="controls">
       <%= check_box_tag "On Site Owner, @resident_owner.on_site_owner,  @resident_owner.on_site_owner,disabled: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
 </center>
</td>
```

But for better UI design, I would create a helper that generates check(the tick icon) or uncheck icon for given value and use it in erb. Eg:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def show_check_icon(boolean_value)
    if boolean_value then 
      "<i class='fa-li fa fa-check-square'></i>"
    else 
      "<i class='fa-li fa fa-square'></i>"
    end 
  end

end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: so i would create the helper and add the checkbox tag to the show page? or just one or the other?

Comment: You can use either check_box_tag or helper, not both. Anyway , I am glad it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I used a similar as @dreamingblackcat, and changed it for font awesome:

```
 def show_check_icon(boolean_value)
    if boolean_value
      %{<i class='fas fa-check'></i>}.html_safe
    else
      %{<i class='fas fa-times'></i>}.html_safe

    end
```